# What is the percentage of Cayley graphs in the family of vertex-transitive graphs?

Tags: permutations, algebraic-graph-theory

Cayley graphs are necessarily vertex transitive, but the converse is not true in general. Is there any general/asymptotic result that discusses the percentage of Cayley graphs in vertex-transitive graphs? Or would this be a hard problem?